# Logout inactive user

Tags: php, parameters, timeout, session-cookies

I have the following code on my website:

```
session_set_cookie_params(7200, '.website.com', '', false, true);
```

If I browse my website, sometimes I will be logged out of my website after the two hours. For example if I am submitting a form, and that's very frustrating.

My question is: how could I solve this problem? Is it possible to logout the user only when he is INACTIVE for 2 hours? And what should be the first timeout value of `session_set_cookie_params`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();
if($_SESSION['loginTime'] < time()+120*60){ logoutfunction(); }
```

The `120` part is the 120 minutes you specified (2 hours). You  You could be really clever and ask the user how long they want to wait before they're logged out :D

You'd also need to replace the `logoutfunction();` with whatever you want to happen if the user should be logged out (probably use `session_destroy(); header("Location: http://yourwebsite.com/login.php");`)

Please let me know if you need any more help with this :)

Comment: Thank you! And what value should I give the first parameter of session_set_cookie_params()?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the `session_set_cookie_params();`. Having researched it, something like this? `session_set_cookie_params(7400, '.website.com', '', false, true);` I have chosen 7400 because that is 200 seconds after the expiry. Experiment with different times and see what works :) You can try `session_set_cookie_params(0, '.website.com', '', false, true);` because that is when the browser closes. I'd try that.

Comment: Thank you, but the lifetime with session_set_cookie_params() has nothing to do with the last activity of the user, so every user will be  logged out after 7400 seconds. I would like to do that only after two hours of inactivity;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save into SESSION an actual time of the last visitor move on your website.

Login function:

```
login_user();
save_actual_time_in_session();
```

when user is logged in, for every page load do:

```
check_if_time_in_session_is_expired(); // if so, do some action, e.g. redirect to login form
save_actual_time_in_session();
```

(@Mattios550 solution won't work because on every HTTP request is `loginTime` value in session refreshed to actual time so it never expires...)